# Enter time stamp into MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently upgraded MySQL to version 5.7.35 and PHP to version 7.4.21.

This PHP script is failing to enter the data into '`my_table`'

```
$hoje = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table(teste_id,data) VALUES (:ftesteid, :fdata)");

$stmt->bindParam(':ftesteid', $testeMaisRecente, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->bindParam(':fdata', $hoje, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
```

Although the variable `$hoje` is correct, it just enters `0000-00-00 00:00:00` into column `data`

Comment: _This PHP script is failing_ Which is the error?

Comment: How is a date in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format of type `PDO::PARAM_INT` …? It’s a _string_ value, not an integer.

Comment: No error is thrown, just a blank page

Comment: `PARAM_STR` instead of `PARAM_INT`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini that's it! It was obvious, but before the upgrade it worked nicely. Grazie!

Comment: @SimoneRossaini write the answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrong type into `bindParam`, instead of `PDO::PARAM_INT` you need `PDO::PARAM_STR`
Reference:

- [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)

Answer (score -1):

// also set variable for enter timezone like this

SET time_zone='+00:00';

//or do this one

CREATE TABLE test_timestamp (
t1  TIMESTAMP
);